# Git: how to return to a past commit to start a branch keeping all commits?

Tags: git

Let's suppose we have this history of commmits:

```
c0 <- c1 <- c2 <- c3 <- c4 (master)
```

how can I get this?

```
c0 <- c1 <- c2 <- c3 <- c4 (master)
            ^
            |- c21 <- c22 (test)
```

This is, keep al the work done,
but starting a new branch from a past point.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a simple checkout :

```
git checkout c2
```

And then start your branch as usual :

```
git checkout -b test
```

Comment: I've done: git checkout c2, and now git log doesn't show following commits (c3, c4), so I don't know how to return to c4.

Comment: Ah: It was: git checkout master. (This returns to c4)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with one line:

```
git checkout -b test c2
```

Or if you just want to create the new branch and without checkout:

```
git branch test c2
```